# How to read tweeter json through d language

Tags: json, d

I have a tweeter json (saved in a file called latest.json) that I parse into the "jasonvalue doc" and i try to read it and print specific data. The code below prints the same data every time and not the datas form the whole json.

```
auto content = to!string(read("latest.json"));
 JSONValue doc = parseJSON(content).object; 
 while (i<3){
    writeln(doc.object["created_at"].str,"\n");
    writeln(doc.object["text"].str,"\n");
    writeln(doc.object["retweet_count"].integer,"\n");
    i++;
 }
```

How can I read all the jason?

Answer (score 5):

You should loop over the array of items. Get the json from twitter and like the example here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline it comes as an array of objects.

So do

```
JSONValue[] doc = parseJSON(content).array;
foreach(tweet; doc) {
    writeln(tweet.object["text"].str);
     // and other info
}
```

that should fix it.

Comment: oh oops I forgot to put in a []. It should work if you have a `JSONValue[]` The tweet would be an individual member of the array returned by parseJSON.array

Comment: When I run the program now it says: "std.json.JSONExcetion@std\json.d<153>:JSONvalue is not an array"